# Angular 2RC4 setter (or detect changes)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

my goal is run action on component B when in component A was action. Of course component A emit event and this is input for component B. It works but not everyitme.

Look at the

http://plnkr.co/edit/A3cE4M

When user click delete from component A one element is removed and event is emit. In component B I display same list (and it works). But also when is use function set list in component `JaroFoo` `_counter` should be increment. It is increment only after init and first remove.

I don't know why. How can I force this increment each time when `_list` is changing?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please read the article of [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior. The output emits the same array several times. Only the first time is it recognized as changed (from null to array). Subsequently when the same array is emitted again, change detection doesn't dedect it as change and no update is happening and therefore not call of the setter.

If you create a copy of the array after each modification using

```
this._list = this._list.slice();
```

then each change is recognized because `slice()` creates a new array instance.

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/jo0JI4?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, you are right. But how I should work with setter on dirrerent array opertions or different types.
 I rebuiled code to object http://plnkr.co/edit/A3cE4M and now is the same. Object propery is changind but not use setter function. I afraid that same will be with boolean or string/number.

Comment: Object is the same as array, but changes on primitive values like string, number, boolean are always recognized.

Comment: After object modification what should I to to detect? Or after array.push.  `this_list = this_list` of course doesn't works. 
It isn't clear for me. Probably for each action I should do something else.

Comment: I explained a basic workaroundfor lists in my answer. In general it's better using observables to notify about changes. See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html